# Multi-checkbox validation

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote the following custom validation annotation for my project to confirm that at least one checkbox of a group of checkboxes is checked:

```
public class ValidateAtLeastOneChecked : ValidationAttribute {
    public string[] CheckBoxFields {get; set;}
    public ValidateAtLeastOneChecked(string[] checkBoxFields) {
        CheckBoxFields = checkBoxFields;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext context) {
        Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type type = instance.GetType();

        foreach(string s in CheckBoxFields) {
            Object propertyValue = type.GetProperty(s).GetValue(instance, null);
            if (bool.Parse(propertyValue.ToString())) {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
        return new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessageString);
    }
}
```

I then use it like this:

```
[ValidateAtLeastOneChecked(new string[] { "Checkbox1", "Checkbox2", "Checkbox3", "Checkbox4" }, ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(ErrorMessageResources),ErrorMessageResourceName="SelectAtLeastOneTopic")]
public bool Checkbox1{ get; set; }
public bool Checkbox2{ get; set; }
public bool Checkbox3{ get; set; }
public bool Checkbox4{ get; set; }
```

The aim was to get the check boxes all validating and keep the validations and their localization contained in the ViewModel. This is working, my only concern is that I expected to find an easy google-paste piece of code for this and did not... Am I missing something easier?

As a secondary question I am attaching this to only one checkbox field, which I think is fine; but is there any unintended consequences of that (other than that any `css` error highlighting would only apply to the one checkbox)?

Comment: I would think that there is a why to put all the checkboxes on a panel and then validate the panel based on the isChecked property of each checkbox.

Comment: Why not have a list of bool with values for each checkbox?  The Model Binder will still be happy, and your validation logic gets easier: `boxes.Any((x) => x == true));`

Answer (score 7):

I'll answer your second question first! The fact that one of your your checkboxes needs to be checked is a validation that is more about your class than one of your checkbox. I mean, individually, a checkbox doesn't **need** to be checked, but your model requires one of them to be. Which is why I would put the validation attribute on your class instead of on one of the checkbox. Then, to show your error message on your client HTML you would need to set `Html.ValidationSummary(true)` in your view.

For your first questions, there a lot of possibles way to do what you did, but your way is fine I believe. I'll propose another one though.

I think you should make another `Model` that would only contains your checkboxes. A `CheckBoxList` or something that is more appropriate in your context (that I know nothing about). Then you could use reflection to get all checkboxes and check if one is checked.

It would look like this :

```
public class ValidateAtLeastOneCheckedAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      Type type = value.GetType();
      IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> checkBoxeProperties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof (bool));

      foreach (PropertyInfo checkBoxProperty in checkBoxeProperties)
      {
         var isChecked = (bool)checkBoxProperty.GetValue(value);
         if (isChecked)
         {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
         }
      }

      return new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessageString);
   }
}

[ValidateAtLeastOneChecked]
public class CheckBoxList
{
   public bool Checkbox1 { get; set; }
   public bool Checkbox2 { get; set; }
   public bool Checkbox3 { get; set; }
   public bool Checkbox4 { get; set; }
   public bool Checkbox5 { get; set; }
}
```

The advantages of using such a solution is that you don't need to write down every property in a `string[]`, which could lead to errors (if you forgot one or wrote one incorrectly). Also, you don't need to use `validationContext.ObjectInstance` since the target of your attribute **is** the instance itself.

I'll review your current code too, because there is three points that I see could be "better" :)

By convention, attributes should end with the suffix `Attribute` (which I changed already in my example). You won't need to write `Attribute` when you use it (as shown in my example, which compiles!).

Also, your brackets are following the Java standard, not the C# one. You should put opening brackets on a new line.

Finally, instead of doing this :

```
Object propertyValue = type.GetProperty(s).GetValue(instance, null);
if (bool.Parse(propertyValue.ToString())) {//...
```

You can cast the `propertyValue` to `bool` directly, it will save you a cast to `string`.